# Adding OpenCV to Native C code through CMake on Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to include Opencv to my native C code in an android studio project through Cmake. I did some research online and downloaded the FindOpenCV.cmake file from online and added it to the app directory of my android project. This is also where the CMakeLists.txt is located. I imported OpenCV onto my Android Studio project as a module using this tutorial: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/setup-opencv-sdk-android-studio.html, and when I run:

```
if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
   System.out.println("Opencv not loaded");
} else {
   System.out.println("Opencv loaded");
}
```

I get that Opencv is loaded.

However, since I'm trying to add OpenCV to my native code, and not the Java code, I don't think I can use this. Here is the CMakeLists I have right now:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} FindOpenCV.cmake)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library(# Specifies the name of the library.
        apriltag

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        src/main/apriltag/apriltag.c
        src/main/apriltag/apriltag_jni.c
        src/main/apriltag/apriltag_quad_thresh.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/g2d.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/getopt.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/homography.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/image_f32.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/image_u8.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/image_u8x3.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/matd.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/pnm.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/string_util.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/svd22.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/time_util.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/unionfind.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/workerpool.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/zarray.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/zhash.c
        src/main/apriltag/common/zmaxheap.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag16h5.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag25h7.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag25h9.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag36artoolkit.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag36h10.c
        src/main/apriltag/tag36h11.c
        )

STRING(REPLACE "-O0" "-O4" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG})
STRING(REPLACE "-O2" "-O4" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE})

include_directories(src/main/apriltag/)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_library(log-lib log)
find_library(jnigraphics-lib jnigraphics)
target_link_libraries(apriltag ${log-lib} ${jnigraphics-lib})
```

Here are the errors I'm getting while building the gradle:

```
By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has 
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but 
CMake did not find one. 
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of 
the following names:
OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
"OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV" 
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been 
installed.
```

So my questions are:

1. Can I use the imported OpenCV or do I have to download a different opencv and store it somewhere else?
2. What do I have to change in my CMakeLists.txt for my gradle to build?

Ideally, I want to build and be able to add `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`  and `using namespace cv` to my c file and add functions that use opencv functions.

Comment: From your outputs it seems like the FindOpenCv.cmake is not being found. Have you tried adding it to {CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}/share/modules and including it in the makefile? 
    include(FindOpenCv)

Comment: No, I can try this! How do I find out what the CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR is?

Comment: Relevant Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10766438/7950680

Comment: Thank you for the link, it was very helpful! I am getting a new error now with this new CMakeLists.txt: Could not find OpenCV_CORE_INCLUDE_DIR, Could not find OPENCV_HIGHGUI_INCLUDE_DIR. Do I have to download other opencv libraries?

Comment: Using Android Studio's C++ New project wizard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958876/can-opencv-for-android-leverage-the-standard-c-support-to-get-native-build-sup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE 21-Oct-19: Deprecated Git/Simpler Way in favor of new AndroidOpenCVGradlePlugin**

**UPDATE 22-May-18: Added missing step number 6.**

**UPDATE 10-May-17: New solution provides proper integration of OpenCV into application with CMake and Android Gradle plugin 2.3.1. Tested using Android Studio 2.3.1.**

**UPDATE 11-May-17: An additional solution has been provided**

There are two ways of including OpenCV.

**Using AndroidOpenCVGradlePlugin**

Visit [https://github.com/ahasbini/AndroidOpenCVGradlePlugin](https://github.com/ahasbini/AndroidOpenCVGradlePlugin?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=43886764) for more details.

<strike>**Git/Simpler Way**</strike>

Visit [https://github.com/ahasbini/Android-OpenCV](https://github.com/ahasbini/Android-OpenCV?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=43886764) for more details.

**Manual/Advanced Way**

To include OpenCV libraries into Android Studio Project, its best to create a new Library Module in the project and port the files from OpenCV Android SDK bundle into it:

1. Create a new module by selecting File>New Module.
2. Select "Android Library", and then enter the details:

   - Library name: `OpenCV`
   - Module name: `opencv`
   - Package name: `org.opencv`
3. Once the new module created, copy the contents of `path_to_opencv_sdk/sdk/java/src` directory into `path_to_your_project/opencv/src/main/java`.
4. Under `main`, create the following directly path: `aidl/org/opencv/engine` and **move** `main/java/org/opencv/engine/OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl` into it.
5. Copy the contents of `path_to_opencv_sdk/sdk/java/res` into `path_to_your_project/opencv/src/main/res`.
6. Create `sdk` folder inside `path_to_your_project/opencv/src/` and copy `path_to_opencv_sdk/sdk/native` folder into it.
7. Within the `opencv` module, create `CMakeLists.txt` file and add the following lines in the following order:

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(OpenCV_DIR "src/sdk/native/jni")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

---

8. Within the `opencv` module, edit the `build.gradle` file as such:

---

```
...
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3200
        versionName "3.2.0"

        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = [jni.srcDirs, 'src/sdk/native/jni/include']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = [jniLibs.srcDirs, 'src/sdk/native/3rdparty/libs', 'src/sdk/native/libs']
        }
    }
}
...
```

---

9. Within the `app` (application module, could be another name) module, create/edit `CMakeLists.txt` file and add the following lines in the following order (Note the different path set to `OpenCV_DIR`):

---

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "../opencv/src/sdk/native/jni")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET_LIB ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

---

10. Within the `app` (application module, could be another name) module, edit the `build.gradle` file as such:

---

```
...    
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':opencv')
}
```

---

11. Do a gradle sync, and now the OpenCV native libs, header files and Java wrapper classes are included.

When project is built and apk is launched, you could inspect the packaged apk under `path_to_project/path_to_app_module/build/output/` (drag the apk onto the text editor tabs of Android Studio)

[image: APK Inspection]

You should see a `libopencv_java3.so` under each abi architecture folder.

Initialize the OpenCV SDK in your java class :

```
public class MyClass {

    static {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And you should see within logcat messages specifying the OpenCV has been loaded (the first error is normal):

```
05-10 10:42:31.451 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to get library list
05-10 10:42:31.452 E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
05-10 10:42:31.452 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library list: ""
05-10 10:42:31.452 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs
05-10 10:42:31.452 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to init OpenCV libs
05-10 10:42:31.452 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Trying to load library opencv_java3
05-10 10:42:32.031 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Library opencv_java3 loaded
05-10 10:42:32.031 D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: First attempt to load libs is OK
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper: General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Version control:               3.2.0
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   Platform:
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Timestamp:                   2016-12-23T13:04:49Z
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Host:                        Linux 4.8.0-25-generic x86_64
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Target:                      Linux 1 x86_64
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake generator:             Ninja
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/ninja
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Configuration:               Release
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:   C/C++:
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
05-10 10:42:32.045 I/OpenCV/StaticHelper:     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/ccache /opt/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-g++ (ver 4.9)
```

Comment: But this is for opencv in my Java files right? I want to be able to add opencv to the native C code

Comment: Oh no, its for c code as well. I added includes that reference opencv header files and it compiled without any errors. I also inspected the  lib that contains the include header file and it size was bigger than without the include, hence i assume CMake linked the opencv library to it properly

Comment: Oh I see, so I tried the steps until step 10 and the gradle did not build properly. I had a previous OpenCV module installed, could that have messed up things?

Comment: Probably, could you see and post what the error is? If gradle failed usually errors show in the message view in Android Studio

Comment: Sure, I actually just deleted the module I made, let me redo the steps and I will post the error.

Comment: One thing I'm doing is in my res folder when I'm copying things over, I'm merging rather than just overwriting. So the previous res file had a strings.xml and I'm adding a attrs.xml file along with it

Comment: Here is the gradle error message: Could not find OpenCV_CORE_INCLUDE_DIR and Could not find OpenCV_HIGHGUI_INCLUDE_DIR. OpenCV required but some headers or libs not found. Please specify it's location with OpenCV_ROOT_DIR env. variable

Comment: That's weird, there is no ```strings.xml``` file within the OpenCV Android SDK ```java``` folder. Are you sure you've downloaded the latest SDK? Here's the link to it just incase: http://opencv.org/releases.html. Latest version is 3.2.0.

Comment: Another error is "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names: OpenCVConfig.cmake opencv-config.cmake, "Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143986/discussion-between-ksivakumar-and-ahasbini).

Comment: Thanks a lot,I was struggling for doing this since 2 days

Comment: @ahasbini - in step 6 and step 8, is there an extra 's' in 'CMakesLists.txt'?

Comment: I might well have missed a step, or maybe the directory structure has changed with OpenCV 3.4.0, but do you need a step to copy the 'sdk' folder into the new module also so that the CMakeLst file can find the jni files in the 'set(OpenCV_DIR "../opencv/src/sdk/native/jni")' line?

Comment: Apologies, I think I've missed a step but can't seem to confirm. Did you copy the `sdk/native` into `opencv/src/sdk`?

Comment: Yes sorry about that @Mick, I've accidentally missed putting this step, just did the edit and it's number 6.

Comment: Thanks @ahasbini! I'll try again later this week and see how I get on.

Comment: @ahasbini - just to note. I tried and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Could the downvoter elaborate the need to down vote the answer?

Answer (score 4):

The manual method outlined by ahasbini worked ([Reg. Adding OpenCV to Native C code through CMake on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766092/reg-adding-opencv-to-native-c-code-through-cmake-on-android-studio/43886764#43886764)), however some minor adjustments were required for the current version of Android Studio/SDK (3.1.3);

1 replace the occurrence of `compile` with `implementation` in (10) app build.gradle ([Still getting warning : Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709870/still-getting-warning-configuration-compile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replace)). And in (9) app CMakeLists.txt ensure to replace `YOUR_TARGET_LIB` with your target lib (e.g. `native-lib`).

2 change the STL to `gnustl_shared` ([Linking errors on Android with OpenCV 3.4.0 and NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677231/linking-errors-on-android-with-opencv-3-4-0-and-ndk)); edit (8) app build.gradle;

```
defaultConfig {
...
externalNativeBuild {
  cmake {
    ...
    arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared"
  }
}
```

This prevents referencing errors within linked opencv libraries (e.g. `error: undefined reference to std:: ...`)

3 To support C++11 ([How to enable C++11 for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667374/how-to-enable-c11-for-android-studio) / [OpenCV Android native code build issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088189/opencv-android-native-code-build-issue)); edit (8) app build.gradle;

```
defaultConfig {
...
externalNativeBuild {
  cmake {
    ...
    cppFlags "-std=c++11"
  }
}
```

Then add the following to (9) app CMakeLists.txt before `add_library()`;

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a")
```

This prevents the following error; `relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object`.

Answer (score 1):

I used @ahasbini's answer and it produced an error when I wanted to access the open cv libs in my native cpp file.

It produced some error when adding the shared libs but only if I accessed their Classes in my file.

Changing

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

To

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED java)
```

Fixed it for me

Comment: Would be happy to help out if you could share the error you were getting. Also if you could elaborate what java here does?

Comment: Am thankful to you. This worked for me too. Don;t know why though.