# Android undefined reference with NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to implement code from

[here](https://github.com/webjb/myrobot)

When trying to compile it, I get these errors:

```
Error:(339) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_fromSurface'
Error:(340) und
Error:(349) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry'
Error:(351) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_lock'
Error:(353) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_release'
Error:(406) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost'
Error:(407) undefined reference to `ANativeWindow_release'
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.012 secs
Information:8 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

`ANativeWindow` gets from 2 c++ .h files, one is

```
#include <android/native_window.h>
```

and other

```
 #include <android/native_window_jni.h>
```

Now, my CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# OpenCV stuff
include_directories(D:\\opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk\\native\\jni\\include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       -ljnigraphics
                       lib_opencv

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

And my gradle file regarding c++ code:

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")

        applicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("androidApplicationId")
        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")
        testInstrumentationRunner globalConfiguration.getAt("testInstrumentationRunner")
        testApplicationId globalConfiguration.getAt("testApplicationId")
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -Werror -fexceptions -std=c++11"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64'
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone would help me with this

Comment: Although this is not related, I would suggest to take a look at my answer regarding OpenCV stuff. Your implementation seems fine however it'll be better to leverage OpenCV's CMake toolchain (which are included within the SDK) to build OpenCV libraries instead of manually doing so as you have in your ```CMakeLists.txt``` file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43886764/2949966

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to link against `libandroid`.

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       -ljnigraphics
                       -landroid # Add this.
                       lib_opencv

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Same way you linked against libjnigraphics.