# How to link Android project against libandroid with Cmake?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So, I have android project with c++ support. There are some undefined references in my project when trying to build c++ code and, after answering my first question, what is the problem with it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926204/android-undefined-reference-with-ndk), I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in your other question?

Comment: @DanAlbert I don't know how to begin with the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Cmake that looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# OpenCV stuff
include_directories(D:\\opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk\\native\\jni\\include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       -ljnigraphics
                       lib_opencv

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

just change the part to be like this:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       -ljnigraphics
                       -landroid # Add this.
                       lib_opencv

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```