# How to compile and share two c++ libraries on an android build using CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I have custom C++ classes which I want to run on my android app. I am successfully binded my C++ files using `CMakeLists`. But as my classes uses opencv, I am getting an issue which is obvious

```
fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
```

Then I tried to add opencv library on my android app, downloaded the open cv android sdk and tired to add it on my project. Below is the folder structure

```
android 
   -> app
       -> opencv2
          All the opencv2 c++ files and folders
       ->folder1
          My custom c++ classes which will import opencv2.
```

The following is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)  # for example

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")

PROJECT(tag)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

 add_library( tag_native
              # Sets the library as a shared library.
              SHARED
              # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
              "./folder1/tag_native.cpp" )


add_library( opencv2
             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED
             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             "./opencv2/" )

set_target_properties(opencv2 PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

This is the sample of my cpp file

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

Everything from c++ compiles well but I am still getting the same issue

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\Brainants with arguments {Technology\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe -C E:\Squtag\Squtag Mobile\android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a opencv2 squtag_native}
  ninja: Entering directory `E:\Squtag\Squtag Mobile\android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/squtag_native.dir/E_/Squtag/Squtag_Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag_Native/squtag_native.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/squtag_native.dir/E_/Squtag/Squtag_Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag_Native/squtag_native.cpp.o 
  C:\Users\BRAINA~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\210~1.611\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi24 --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Brainants Technology/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64" --sysroot="C:/Users/Brainants Technology/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot"  -Dsqutag_native_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/squtag_native.dir/E_/Squtag/Squtag_Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag_Native/squtag_native.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\squtag_native.dir\E_\Squtag\Squtag_Mobile\ios\Runner\Squtag_Native\squtag_native.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/squtag_native.dir/E_/Squtag/Squtag_Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag_Native/squtag_native.cpp.o -c "E:/Squtag/Squtag Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag Native/squtag_native.cpp"
  E:/Squtag/Squtag Mobile/ios/Runner/Squtag Native/squtag_native.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
  #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Forget about the guideline in your link. It's totally about using opencv in Java.
It's simple like you did with your C++ files using CMakeLists.
1. Build OpenCV libraries for android devices
2. Copy the libraries and headers to your Android project and link that with CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I tried that as well, but my import system didnt work. Basically I had to change the important statement by excluding the library  name. The thing I wanted to know was how to bind the existing c++ code to a new library and use it on my original c++ file.

Comment: The problem seems more likely about linking libraries with CMake. If that's a problem, whether it's Android or not isn't important since you succeed binding main C++ to Android projects. I'm not very good at CMake, so why don't you try searching linking libraries with CMake or reask with CMake tag?

Comment: If you're using `CMake` to link the library, you must build it first.
Build the OpenCV library to make `.so` or `.a` libraries. And then, you can link the libraries and headers. Check out https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/ndk/opencv-without-java this.

Comment: What I meant a *library*, is a built C++ `.so` or `.a` libraries, not the source codes of the entire OpenCV library

Comment: Your CMake syntax `add_library(opencv2 ...)` is incorrect. This command accepts *source files* (not a directory) as remaining arguments. Consider reading the OpenCV tutorial for importing OpenCV using CMake [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html). It is the widely-accepted and supported way to import OpenCV into your CMake project.

Comment: I indeed tried to add second parameter to the core.hpp file hoping that other files will be imported compile time. I just dont know if I should use whole source code in c++ or use precompiled .so/.a file and how. Also I just went through the link but I am not able to grasp how `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )` is supposed to work on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you get is telling you that it cannot find opencv include file:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

you need to locate the opencv2 folder, and pass it to cmake as an additional include directory:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html

example: [Adding OpenCV to Native C code through CMake on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766092/adding-opencv-to-native-c-code-through-cmake-on-android-studio)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(OpenCV_DIR "src/sdk/native/jni")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

or you can use this approach:
https://github.com/ahasbini/Android-OpenCV/blob/master/app/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: This worked amazingly. Thanks for all the references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cmake project couldn't find the installed opencv, so either you set your path to `${complete_path_to_opencv_installation}/apt` or you install opencv in *common installation folder*

Either way, you'll need to propagate this to your project: 
In case you install this in typical place (e.g. `/usr/local/` in linux you'll need to set `export PATH=$PATH:${opencv_installation_path}` or `c:\Path` in Windows, then set *Path* in *Environment Variable*.

By doing so, the `find_package(OpenCV)` should be able to find the opencv library and `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` is set.
This **CMakeLists.txt** should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

or you could also `set OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "./app/opencv2"` before `include_directories`
to propagate `opencv2/core.hpp`.

You could also interested to this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766092/adding-opencv-to-native-c-code-through-cmake-on-android-studio) about using opencv with android.